# How to get all posts on my Facebook Wall

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying get posts on my facebook wall using facebook-sdk in python.
I am using this code for all the posts.

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=access_token, version='2.2')
profile=graph.get_object('me')
posts=graph.get_connections(profile['id'],'posts')
for post in posts['data']:
    print post
```

It turns out to be it is showing posts only made by me not on my wall.
How can i get all posts on my wall specially birthday posts and all.

**Update**

How to get all posts made by other users on my wall.Feed and Posts dont take care of that.

Comment: You can’t. There is `/me/feed`, which is a super-set of `/me/posts` – but your app will only get posts whose authors have granted it `user_posts` permission, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/user/feed#read

Comment: How to get all posts made by others on my wall in facebook

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38854095/how-to-get-all-posts-on-my-facebook-wall?noredirect=1#comment65072881_38854095